# Block PR merge on GitLab when there is no valid JIRA ID

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, jira, gitlab-ci-runner

I want to block the PR merge automatically when there is no backing valid JIRA id. I'm using GitLab. Any suggestion/reference links to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a job to check if `JIRA` id is present. If it's not present fail the job.

Then in settings ( settings --> merge requests ) enable only allow merge when pipleines succeed.

[image]

Comment: thanks, I have already enabled it however can you share some reference code or link to refer about the code that goes inside the pipeline job?

Comment: I have integrated JIRA on GitLab however can you share some reference code or link to refer about the code that goes inside the pipeline job? https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b72Sdn34G-sl5jJverJdfl7JYK7Gc1qp/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xQvyA68l1MrRd8_pS_RlhP8xhUwDbkNJ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Am not much familiar with Jira and how you r using it. Also have you check on how are u going to check 'no backing valid JIRA id'.

Comment: I thought of making a curl request in the Pipeline Job to JIRA host to get the details of JIRA id and check if it is valid or not including its current status of it on JIRA side. My Gitlab and JIRA are integrated with each other already, I though if there is anyway we can do with little to less coding (making curl, etc), something out of box?

Comment: Yes that should work curl and check if the id is valid and according to the response decide to exit or not. If you can add both type of responses you are getting (valid/invalid) i can help with the gitlab job.